# javascript insert test before </table> in textarea

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea

I have a textarea for entering an actor and character into a table, with javascript, but have to have buttons to add the `'<table class="xxxx">'` and a separate button for the closing `</table>`, is there a way to modify the following code to add the new actor as character table row before the closing `</table>`, therefore eliminating the need for extra buttons?

```
function addtxt(input) {
var obj=document.getElementById(input);
var actortxt = document.getElementById('actor').value;
var chartxt = document.getElementById('character').value;
obj.value+="<tr><td>"+actortxt+"</td><td>as</td><td>"+chartxt+"</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: This Code Project example might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14995/Dynamically-add-and-remove-rows-in-a-HTML-table

Comment: thanks but I do not have the table on the page, the source `<table></table>` is in a textarea to save the table into a DB, which is working, but I need to add the `<tr>....</tr>` to the textarea before the `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background:grey">

<input type="text" id="actor"/>
<input type="text" id="character"/>

<div id="therefore"></div>

<script>
var i=0;
function addtxt() {
    i++;
    var actortxt = document.getElementById('actor').value;
    var chartxt = document.getElementById('character').value;
    if(i%3==1){
        var open1 = '<table class="xxxx">';
        var close1 = '';
        i=0;
    }else {
        var open1= '';
        var close1 = '</table>';
    }
    document.getElementById('therefore').innerHTML+=open1+"<tr><td>"+actortxt+"</td><td>as</td><td>"+chartxt+"</td></tr>"+close1;

}
document.addEventListener('click',addtxt,false);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary `<div>` and put the textarea html string into it.

Then manipulate the table element inside the temp `<div>` as if it was in the page.

Once done set the textarea value from the innerHTML of the temporary `<div>`

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor')


var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = editor.value;

var table = tempDiv.querySelector('table'),
  newRow = table.insertRow(),
  cell1 = newRow.insertCell(),
  cell2 = newRow.insertCell();

cell1.textContent = 'Row 2 Cell 1';
cell2.textContent = 'Row 2 Cell 2';

editor.value = tempDiv.innerHTML;
```

```html
<textarea id='editor' rows="15" cols="200">

<p>Some other element</p>
<table>
 <tr><td> Row 1 Cell 1</td><td>Row 1 Cell 2</tr>
</table>

</textarea>
```

Comment: I will take a look in the morning, at the moment none of these seem to work for me, please take a look here for my form [link](http://www.teeseyed.com/dev_js/) and see what I am looking for, enter the actor and character at the bottom and click 'add table start, then 'Add Cast Member' then 'Add Table End', I am trying to achieve this without having to add the `<table> </table>` buttons. I thought it would be as easy as locating `</table>` and inserting the `<tr>....</tr>` row before it, but how do I do this in JS?

Comment: Whole concept seems like a very strange approach when you could do it in the DOM instead of in a textarea. The DOM is a very powerful html parser

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, with a bit of tinkering I have got this solution to work:

```
    function inserttext(tarea){
        var obj=document.getElementById(tarea);
        var maintext =  document.getElementById(tarea).value;
        var actortxt = document.getElementById('actor').value;
        var chartxt = document.getElementById('character').value;
        var chstr = '<tr><td>'+actortxt+'</td><td>as</td><td>'+chartxt+'</td></tr>';
//      alert('Main:'+maintext+'--'+'Actor:'+actortxt+'--'+'Char:'+chartxt+'--'+chstr);
        var position = maintext.indexOf('</table>');
//      alert('table close found at :'+position);
        var newtext= maintext.substr(0, position) + chstr + maintext.substr(position);
//      alert('New Text:'+newtext);
        obj.value=newtext;
    }
```